# Trying to make a For Loop that adds something in Visual Basic; not getting right answer

Tags: vb.net

I need to make a console app for a class, and it has to compute the following using a For Next loop: 4 + 8 + 12 + 16 + 20 .... + 208

Here's what I have:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim z As Integer = 4

For x = 0 To 208 Step 4
    z = z + 4
    Console.WriteLine(z)
Next
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6166/64132)

Comment: Your main failure is not to use the debugger. Step through your code and display the content of your variables in each step - then you will (hopefully) understand what happens. Or if you don't know how to use the debugger, add an additional line `Console.WriteLine(x)` to your loop.

Answer (score 5):

On each iteration, you are adding `4` to `z`, so you are actually computing 4 + 4 + 4 + ... + 4. What you really want to do is to add `x` to `z`:

```
Dim x As Integer = 0
Dim z As Integer = 4

For x = 0 To 208 Step 4
    z = z + x
    Console.WriteLine(z)
Next
```